# openpyxl AttributeError when i attempt to add data in dict from multiple sheets

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to add the data from Excel into a dictionary. But an error appears when I use `.append(total_sales)` and of course no problem if I do `+=total_sales`, except that I obtain the sum instead of having the data for the 3 separate months. Can you help me find the error in my code?

```
import openpyxl
#juste recuperer les valeurs pas les formules "data_only=True"
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook("octobre.xlsx", data_only=True)
wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook("novembre.xlsx", data_only=True)
wb3 = openpyxl.load_workbook("decembre.xlsx", data_only=True)


def add_data_from_wb(wb, data):
    sheet = wb.active
    for row in range(2, sheet.max_row):
        item = sheet.cell(row, 1).value
        if not item:
            break
        total_sales = sheet.cell(row, 4).value
        if data.get(item):
            data[item].append(total_sales)
        else:
            data[item] = total_sales

data_dict = {}
add_data_from_wb(wb1, data_dict)
add_data_from_wb(wb2, data_dict)
add_data_from_wb(wb3, data_dict)
print(data_dict)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand (*from your code*) the exact format of your spreadsheets and the final dictionary you're expecting as an output. I imagine that you expect a dictionary with items/strings as keys and lists of integers/total_sales as the values.

I can reproduce your error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

and that's because you're initiating a dictionary with integers rather than a list of integers. This can be fixed by using

```
data[item] = [total_sales]
```

(*line 18 of your code*).

You can also simply your code by making a list of files and a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from collections import defaultdict

l = ["octobre.xlsx", "novembre.xlsx", "decembre.xlsx"]

def add_data_from_wbs(files):
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for f in files:
        sheet = load_workbook(f, data_only=True).active
        for row in range(2, sheet.max_row+1):
            item = sheet.cell(row, 1).value
            total_sales = sheet.cell(row, 4).value
            data[item].append(total_sales)
    return dict(data)
    
d = add_data_from_wbs(l)
```

A variant, using [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) / [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

d = (
    pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f, header=None, skiprows=1) for f in l])
        .groupby(0)[3].agg(list).to_dict()
)
```

Output :

```
print(d) #{'Item1': [100, 300], 'Item2': [200], 'Item3': [300, 500, 400]}
```

Used inputs :

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do. I'll try to be more precise next time :)
Thank you for taking the time to try to understand and answer.